# Venn diagram - choose the odd man out

Tags: notation

```
  Which one of the following statements is not correct in the context of venn 
 diagram method ?

 (1) It can be used to represent classes as well as propositions
 (2) It is a method of testing the validity of arguments
 (3) It represents both the premises of a syllogism in one diagram
 (4) It requires two overlapping circles for the two premises of a standard- 
 form categorical syllogism.
```

Comment: this is a solid question for which an answer is required. not sure what is wrong with the question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is 4 that is not correct. Consider the following diagram.

[image]

It represents both premises that "no IT applications are IT operations" and that "no IT operations are IT applications"... but the circles are not overlapping, which (4) states is a necessity.